# What do negative values on bright sources in TIRSPEC mean?

Tags: photography, image-processing, infrared, fits

I opened a FITs image data from [TIRSPEC](https://www.tifr.res.in/%7Edaa/tirspec/) (NIR imaging) (an HgCdTe infrared imaging sensor) on DS9 and I saw that some of the bright stars have black patches at the center (negative values).

Can you please explain what this means?

Comment: I've got an answer prepared, but before I post, I'd like some more details.  What is the source of the sky image?  What telescope? What imaging technology (cmos, CCD, something made by NASA?)  Also why do you tag "star-formation"?  This has nothing to do with DS9 (that just displays the image) And everything to do with the telescope and imaging technology, so please tell us more about that.

Comment: It's the data from TIRSPEC (NIR imaging). CCDs have been used to image.

Comment: Assuming it's this [TIRSPEC](https://www.tifr.res.in/~daa/tirspec/), it's a Hawaii1K HgCdTe detector, not a CCD.

Comment: My guess would be that the centers of the stars saturated the detector, and something in the post-processing translated that to negative counts.

Comment: Yes you get the same thing with JWST images, it seems to be a feature of HgCdTe technology that it returns zero or negative values when oversaturated.